# Why was my "not an answer" flag denied?

Tags: discussion, support, answers, flagging

A little while ago I flagged [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/510096/169120) as "Not an answer", as it is just a bunch of seemingly random screenshots posted by someone who was neither the OP nor the author of the other answer to the question. There is no context to the screenshots, or really any text whatsoever. It doesn't seem like an *incorrect* answer, as that should just be down-voted. I don't think it's an answer to a different question, although I could be wrong. I didn't flag it because I disagree with it. It's just a complete [*non sequitur*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/non%20sequitur).

However, the flag was declined - *"flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer"*

I've read through the relevant [FAQ item](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185073/203631) on Meta.SE and some other related posts, and I don't think this fits in to the *When should I not use this flag?* section of the answer. Should I resubmit this as a custom flag and explain to the mod my thoughts, or just let it go and let voters have their say on its usefulness?

Comment: (I'm not sure the "Support" tag is relevant here...)

Comment: @ThomasW. I tagged it `Support` because, as the tag description says, I needed help with one or more of the site's features, namely flagging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those screenshots detail a method of removing the package(s).  WHile it's not a very good quality answer, it's still technically an answer.

If I were looking in the flags queue I would have agreed with the moderator who did that and say "It *does* provide an answer, albeit not a high quality one".

To be honest, this is one of those really low quality edge-cases, in my opinion, but it still qualifies as an answer.  You should actually *look* at the content in the screenshots and you'll see it is a step-by-step method of removing the package via Software Center.

---

**To that end:**

You can just downvote the answer because it is low quality or you disagree with it in some way, or maybe if it's just a "bad answer".  I think it's very very low quality, and downvoted it because of that, but there's a reason the "Downvote" function exists.  ;)

Comment: This is kind of what I was thinking as well - it's definitely an edge case, and possibly a different mod might have chosen differently, but it is what it is. Thanks for the feedback!